# Prevent Hyperlinks to Bad Domains

Tags: security, seo

I have a forum, user's can post comments, they can also enable/disable and approve comments; however, I can't always trust users will disapprove comments linking to bad domains. Like these: http://www.mywot.com/en/forum/3823-275-bad-domains-to-blacklist

My question is two part:

1. If a user does hyperlink to a 'bad domain' like those in the link above, will my forum/forum-category/forum-category-thread be penalised by it, and even if so if I add no-follow to the forum thread's links?
2. Is there a free API service out there, that I can make a request to to get a list of bad domains, so I can then filter them out of users' posts?

I maybe being paranoid, but it's probably because I'm not too SEO savvy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual algorithms aren't public, but this is what I found looking around the 'net.

1) [Google's Web master Guidelines](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=8522&answer=35769) says that it may lower ranking for sites that participate in link schemes. As an example of a link scheme, they give **"Links to web spammers or bad neighborhoods on the web"**. NoFollow may or may not have impact on it, but the consensus seems to be that it doesn't.

2) You can use either of [Google's two safe browsing APIs](https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/) to check if sites have been found to be phishing and/or malware sites.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I failed to mention, I did try implementing Google's Safe Query API V2, but it's quite advanced and requires a cron job; guess I'll give it another go.

Answer (score 1):

If your website linking to bad domains, that will definitely harm your website but again; it is depending upon outgoing links ratio.

I strongly recommend recruit forum moderator from active members who can manually moderate forum post and will help you to save from spamming.

I am not sure but many forums allow various restriction like: 
 - Only members having number of post can keep link in forum reply
 - Only specified months/days old member can share links
 - Only particular number of links are allowed in forum post.

Kindly check for such facilities that can help you to restrict the users.